# how to run db.adminCommand() using pymongo for mongodb 3.6

Tags: mongodb, python, mongodb-3.4, mongodb-3.6

I want to run this command and get it's output using pymongo module.

```
db.adminCommand({getParameter: 1, logLevel: 1})
```

or say I want to run this command

```
db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, disableJavaScriptJIT: false } )
```

basically I want to get the configurations settings using mongodb shell only. I don't have access to configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

On mongo shell:

```
db.adminCommand({getParameter: 1, logLevel: 1})
```

> { "logLevel" : 0, "ok" : 1 }

On python:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

server = 'localhost'

port = 27017

client = MongoClient(server, port)

print(client.admin.command(({'getParameter': 1, 'logLevel': 1})))
```

> {'logLevel': 0, 'ok': 1.0}